# How to get TRAMP to respect group sticky bit?

Tags: tramp, files, permissions

In using TRAMP to create a new file in a remote (Unix) directory, I discovered that TRAMP is not respecting the group sticky bit in that directory.

As is standard on a Unix system, the group sticky bit says that any new file created in that directory shall have the same group ownership as the directory itself.  My own userid is `nr`, and my default group is also called `nr`.  Because of the sticky bit, new files created *on* the remote host are owned by `nr` but have group ownership `ta105`.  But new files created using TRAMP have group ownership `nr`.

How can I modify or configure TRAMP so that it respects the group sticky bit in the remote directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in Tramp. I will fix it, available with the next Emacs version (27.1) and/or Tramp version (2.4.2).